# Kohana 3.3 ORM 'has_many' and 'through' case problems with different model and table name

Tags: kohana-3.3

I can't seem to get the ORM "has_many" and "through" case working when I use PSR-0 model names that have more than one word because my model is User_Business_Unit and my table is user_business_unit.  For example:

Here is the has_many relationship in my 'User' model:

```
protected $_has_many = array(
  'business_unit' => array(
     'model' => 'Business_Unit',
     'through' => 'user_business_unit',
     'foreign_key' => 'user_id',
     'far_key' => 'business_unit_id',
);
```

If I do a

```
echo $user->has('business_unit', 2);
```

for example, it will work.  But if I do a

```
$user->add('business_unit', 2);
```

it fails because it tries to instantiate the model with the 'through' alias "user_business_unit", but the model is "User_Business_Unit".

If I change my 'through' setting to "User_Business_Unit" then the add() case works but the has() case fails because it tries to query the table "User_Business_Unit" but the table is "user_business_unit".

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

I suppose I could rename my table to be "User_Business_Unit", but that hardly seems like a good solution.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `'model' => 'User_Business_Unit',`?

Comment: No, this is correct.  I did have a mistake in my description which I have corrected (I was using the User model as the example, not the Company model...)

Comment: I can only assume this is a bug in Kohana and hopefully it will be fixed.